# ocassioanlly slow after upgrading to .net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, .net

We have a decent size web app that was .net 2.0. we upgraded it to .net 4.0 and no occasionally page loads go slow. I would say one out of ten times or so, a refresh and it'll load near instant again but i'm not sure what could cause these hang ups after upgrading to 4.0.
are there any common problems after updating that could cause this?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There could be some other reason however the first comes in mind is Application Pool shutdown which may cause a little delay in page load. Have you verified if the random page slowness is caused by your Application Pool is shutdown?

To Verify if it is not related with Application Pool, set AppPool shutdown to 0 so it will not shutdown and then check if page reload still take time.